# Vue with webpack, how can I find the app data in the browser debugger?

Tags: vuejs2

(Taking first steps with web development but it appears that I'm currently unable to use even the most fundamental tools, like e.g. a browser debugger.)

When I init a new vue.js 2.x project as follows...

```
sudo npm install --global vue-cli
vue init simple vue1
```

(accepting defaults for all prompts)

... and then proceed to open the generated index.html in Chromium, I more or less see what I would expect in the browser debugger. More specifically, I can enter the following in the browser console...

```
this.app.$data.greeting = "Blah"
```

... and see the page greeting change immediately, as I would expect.

However, when I use a webpack template...

```
vue init webpack-simple vue2
cd vue2
npm install
npm run dev
```

... I'm unable to find the data in the browser console. From the code in App.vue I would expect that there should be a `msg` or `data` property somewhere, but I get lost pretty quickly when I try to look for it. I do find `.msg` in the served build.js but the code is so obfuscated that I fail to determine the full path to it. I'd probably be able to find it if I invested a lot more time but somehow I feel that it cannot be that complicated and that I must be missing something.

So, how would one go about finding this methodically?

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools is a MUST when developing with Vue.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "simple" vue template save the vue instance in a global `app` var that is accessible everywhere :

```
<script>
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  ...
})
</script>
```

With the "webpack-simple" template, the `vue-loader` loader wraps the components in a CommonJS module (which are closures and therefore prevent variables to be directly accessible outside the module).

To remediate this issue for debugging purpose, you can use [Vue devtools](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools).

Eventually you can also make your app variable accessible in dev environment.
Define a `DEV` variable in webpack.config.js (remove it for production):

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    DEV: true
  })
]
```

And expose what you want in your code :

```
if (typeof DEV !== 'undefined' && DEV) {
  window.app = app; //this block will be removed by the build step
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Vue DevTools](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools) is your best bet. When you are running Vue through webpack, `this` will be the `window` object, not the Vue instance.

(Technically, you can also do `window.Vue = new Vue({ })` or `var foobar = new Vue({}); window.Vue = foobar` and then access Vue properties at `window.Vue.$data.greeting` or whatever but the devtools are designed for this functionality and will be a lot easier for you)